# in-app purchase creation in apstore ?

Tags: iphone

I have an application with some in-app purchase in IPhone. Now i want to add a new version of my application with an extra in-app purchase. I need to keep the existing one as same. But to add an extra subscription type in place. How i can add this with in my itunes account. Can anybody provide the step by step procedure for that. Any help will be greatly appreciated.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ii's userful blog, follow this:-
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-in-app-purchases/

I used this blog...

Answer (score 1):

So you sign in to iTunes Connect.

Select your app, select manage in app purchase section.
And add a new in-app,just like the first one,filling all the information needed.